# Spring 6 Upgrade Issue | JSON Response having extra "ArrayList" and "$type"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When using old version of spring [4], below was the JSON response:

```json
{
    "processStatus": "0",
    "processStatusDescription": "",
    "processErrorMessage": "",
    "registrationLocator": [
            {                
                "RegistrarCode": "1042",
                "RegistrarLocCode": "KA008",
                "RegistrarPhoneNumber": "1-866-771-0140"                
            }        
    ],
    "processLoc": "KA",
    "processAlternatives": true
}
```

After upgrade to Spring version 6, below is the JSON response

```json
{
    "processStatus": "0",
    "processStatusDescription": "",
    "processErrorMessage": "",
    "registrationLocator": [
        "ArrayList",
        [
            {
                "$type": "LinkedHashMap",
                "RegistrarCode": "1042",
                "RegistrarLocCode": "KA008",
                "RegistrarPhoneNumber": "1-866-771-0140"                
            }
        ]
    ],
    "processLoc": "KA",
    "processAlternatives": true
}
```

You can notice extra "ArrayList" and "$type" properties coming up now.

Can someone please help to make the JSON response same as old one [Spring 4] ?

Below is the controller method:

```
@GetMapping(value = {REGISTRAR_LOCATOR})
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> registrarLocator(RegistrarLocatorVO requestVO, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    
    try {   
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = registrarLocatorUtiliy.getRegistrar(requestVO, webRequestContext, request);
                            
        return responseMap;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception in registrarLocator => ", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: The original response already had the `$type` so that isn't new.

Comment: @M. Deinum Sorry, $type  was not in first response. Corrected now. Can you please tell why extra "ArrayList" and "$type" is coming up in new Spring 6 version update ?

Comment: Upgraded Jackson version, which probably includes this information.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade in Jackson is "causing" this as it nows maps the type of Object as well. You really should create a POJO to get this mapped correctly.

```
public class Registrar {
 private String RegistrarCode;
 private String RegistrarLocCode;
 private String RegistrarPhoneNumber;

 // Getters and Setters
}
```

```
public class RegistrarResponse {
    private String processStatus;
    private String processStatusDescription;
    private String processErrorMessage;
    private String processLoc;
    private boolean processAlternatives;

    private List<Registrar> registrationLocator;
    
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Then update your code to

```
@GetMapping(value = {REGISTRAR_LOCATOR})
public @ResponseBody RegistrarResponse registrarLocator(RegistrarLocatorVO requestVO, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    
    try {   
        RegistrarResponse response = registrarLocatorUtiliy.getRegistrar(requestVO, webRequestContext, request);
                            
        return response;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception in registrarLocator => ", ex);
    }
}
```

Class names are, of course, only suggestions.

Comment: I cannot change the method return type as suggested by you above.  Anything else that can stop having these extra properties in json ?

Comment: Why can't you change it? It will return the JSON you expect so it shouldn't be an issue for the clients.